# Which pair of combinations comes first in the increasing lexicographic order: {2, 4, 5, 6} or {1, 3, 5, 6}?

Tags: combinatorics

Textbook answer: {1, 3, 5, 6}

I did not learn simple lexicographic ordering for combinations (only permutations). The only type of ordering for combinations I did was Gray-code order.

Can someone please kindly explain how to arrive at the answer {1, 3, 5, 6}? I don't want to make any wrong assumptions.

Comment: By "which pair of combinations comes first" do you mean "which combination comes first"? How is $\{1,3,5,6\}$ a "pair" of combinations???

Comment: The pair is {1, 3, 5, 6} and {2, 4, 5, 6}.

Comment: Then what's the **other** pair? How can you ask "**which** pair" when there's only one pair? How can the answer to "which pair" be $\{1,3,5,6\}$ if $\{1,3,5,6\}$ is not a pair?

Comment: I see what you mean now. I copied the entire textbook question, so I am not sure what they mean by which pair when there is just one pair...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest of $\{1,3,5,6\}$ is $1$.  The smallest of $\{2,4,5,6\}$ is $2$.  Since $1<2$, we conclude $\{1,3,5,6\}<\{2,4,5,6\}$.

If the smallest elements agreed, we would then consider the second-smallest elements, and so on.

Comment: Okay, that is what I was thinking, but I didn't know if that was the wrong way to go about it. Thanks so much!